# How can I install a provider for linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, linked-server, pervasive

I have a provider for a linked server called PervasiveOLEDB.11.0 installed on a sql server 2005 machine. It always me to have a connection to a pervasive sql database.

I would like to use this same provider on a sql server 2012 machine.

Is there a way to transfer this provider from the 2005 to the 2012 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'provider' is the driver required to allow SQL Server to talk to the remote server. These are normally installed pieces of software, so can't simply be copied between machines.

While not being overly familiar with PervasiveDB, I would assume that like most other manufacturers drivers, it will be included in their client release, which is available for download here - http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/pages/default.aspx

Once you've installed this, then you can build your linked server connection. Within SSMS you can right click on your existing Linked Server and make a create script which you can use on your SQL2012 instance. Though be warned that this won't copy all the security details (passwords in particular), so you may need to look this up in the documentation, or have a new user created in the target database.

Sometimes you can have issues with different versions of client software, differing client setup or not getting the permissions identical on the rebuild. You can avoid this in future (or make someone's life a lot easier in the future) by documenting everything as you set it up.

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed answer +1. unfortunately i did install the client and it did not add the appropriate provider. i also installed the server with the same results. pervasive needs to be kicked in the nuts.

Comment: Make sure that you are installing the 64bit version of the driver if you have the 64bit version of SQL Server installed (which you probably do).  If they only provide a 32bit driver it isn't going to work without SQL Server also being 32bit.

Comment: @mrdenny thanks so much for your reply. yes i do have both 64 bit versions

Comment: Even after installing the driver, in this case FoxPro OLE DB, it still does not show up under there.