# Pervasive linked server provider missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, pervasive

I am having the same problem as [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34353/20489).

I installed Pervasive v11 (which does have 64bit `ODBC` drivers) and I still do not see Pervasive listed as a provider when trying to create a linked server in SQL Server Express 2008 R2. Does anyone have any ideas what to try?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a System DSN in order to connect to it using the ODBC drivers from SSMS/SQL Server - simple installing the drivers is not enough. I had  to do the same in order to connect to an older instance that our company uses. Here is an excellent link that will help guide you through the process:

http://discoverysoftware.com/support/kb/acorn-docs/bridges-acorn-docs/odbc-bridges/odbc-set-up-pervasive-sql/

Once you have set up the DSN within the System Data Sources you will be able to create a linked server to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is no longer available (nor is it archived by the Wayback Machine).